# form submit not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, forms

i want to delete data in database using bootstrap modal dan php

button to call modal

```
<a href="#" class="deleteDarah" id="<?php echo $data['id_darah']?>">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span>Hapus
    </button>
</a>
```

javascript to pass value and open modal

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".deleteDarah").click(function(e) {
        var m = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/modal/modalDeleteDarah.php",
            type: "GET",
            data : {id_darah: m,},
            success: function (ajaxData){
            $("#modalDeleteDarah").html(ajaxData);
            $("#modalDeleteDarah").modal('show',{backdrop: 'true'});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

the modal

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteDarahLabel">Hapus Data Darah</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="action.php" method="post">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Apakah anda yakin akan menghapus data <?php echo $_GET['id_darah'] ?> ? </label>
                    <input type="text" name="id_darah" value="<?php echo $_GET['id_darah']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="hapusDarah" class="btn btn-success"><span class="fa fa-save" style="margin-right: 5px" id="hapusDarah"></span>Hapus</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

action.php

```
if (isset($_POST['hapusDarah'])) {
    $id_darah= $_POST['id_darah'];
    $sql="delete from darah where id_darah='$id_darah'";
    $query= mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql)  or die("error: ".mysqli_error($koneksi));
    header('location:../admin/dashboard.php?page=darah');
}
```

i try using `input` and `button` to `submit` but the page didn't change, it's like 'action' in 'form' is empty

Comment: the modal is success to be called, but the submit button not working

Comment: Your HTML tags are mismatched.  Consider investing in an IDE that will point out issues like that to you.  At the minimum, run your (rendered) HTML through something like [this](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Comment: why have you got a button inside a hyperlink?? Makes no sense.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: i thing is not about HTML, before i create this model for update data, i create modal to insert data and it work, the modal structure is no different, the different is ajax, insert modal not using ajax

Comment: Did you check for any errors in your console? I would suspect though that the problem is related to what Patrick said - the HTML is malformed and therefore maybe the browser does not consider that you have a valid `<form>` to submit.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the input, i will change later

Comment: @aDyson no, there is no error in console, like i said before, its like the action is empty

Comment: Try changing the structure to `<form class="form-horizontal" action="action.php" method="post"><div class="modal-body"><label class="col-form-label">Apakah anda yakin akan menghapus data <?php echo $_GET['id_darah'] ?> ? </label>
                    <input type="text" name="id_darah" value="<?php echo $_GET['id_darah']; ?>"/></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="submit" name="hapusDarah" class="btn btn-success"><span class="fa fa-save" style="margin-right: 5px" id="hapusDarah"></span>Hapus</button></div></form>` so the tags are not crossing over each other and elements are all valid.

Comment: @andruwoei  Please show us (by updating your question) the HTML that is returned as the response of the ajax request.  You will find this in your browser's network inspector.  If your modal is currently being displayed properly, which you said it is, then this is most likely _not_ an ajax problem.

Comment: @andruwoei "it's like the action is empty"..yeah but the action is _not_ empty in your sample, so clear that isn't the issue (unless the sample is wrong!). More likely the bad structure - as I explained, if the browser cannot parse the HTML properly, it will think that the form does not exist, and therefore the button cannot submit the form.

Comment: @ADyson i try it and success, thank for find solution for my 3 hours problem

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid because you have open and closing tags crossing over each other, and elements not closed properly at all. Therefore your browser cannot parse it correctly and so does not know that your `<form>` exists. Because there is no form registered with the browser, clicking the Submit button cannot do anything.

Specifically you've got issues such as

```
<div>
<form>
</div>
</form>
```

where the opening and closing tags cross over each other and so the structure is unclear.
 You also have things like

```
<input type="text" name="y" value="x">
```

where there should be `/>` at the end to close the tag (because it doesn't have a separate closing tag).

Try changing the structure to  so the tags are not crossing over each other and elements are all valid:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="action.php" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label class="col-form-label">Apakah anda yakin akan menghapus data <?php echo $_GET['id_darah'] ?> ? </label>
        <input type="text" name="id_darah" value="<?php echo $_GET['id_darah']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" name="hapusDarah" class="btn btn-success">
            <span class="fa fa-save" style="margin-right: 5px" id="hapusDarah"/>Hapus</button>
    </div>
</form>
```